# Angular2 full-width responsive carousel module?

Tags: angular, carousel

I'm trying to find an Angular2 module that provides full-width carousel functionality.  Is anyone aware of one, or some sample code I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-carousel) has worked for me, and it was easy to set up.

Edit:

This carousel takes up the space of the container you put it in, like in their example:

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 400px">
  <carousel [sources]="imageSources" [config]="config"></carousel>
</div>
```

Simple enough!

Comment: Okay sure, I can be long-winded.

Comment: And I just realized this question is from over a year ago, not a couple of weeks... oh well.

Comment: Thanks for edition your answer. :D Bear in mind that you are not only answering the question to help the OP. You are also helping future readers. That means it doesn't matter how old a question is. Your insights are appreciated if you believe you can help future readers.

Comment: Hopefully it can help someone! Angular can be extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Simple Angular carousel component](https://github.com/PikusSpbSandbox/carousel-angular) for Angular 14+

It has pretty simple setup and it does the job for me.

Installation: `npm i carousel-angular`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken Angular2 should be backwards compatible with Angular1. Would you consider using an existing module and using ngUpgrade. An example carousel might be [Angular-Slick](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick). I found an article about [upgrading apps to Angular2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html).

Comment: Yes, I suppose I would if there are no existing options that I can just plug into my app.  Thanks for the links, I may go that route.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [ngx-drag-scroll](https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll), it has features like mouse drag to scroll and hide scrollbar etc.

Usage example:

```
<div drag-scroll drag-scroll-y-disabled="true" scrollbar-hidden="true" >
  <img *ngFor="let image of imagelist" [src]="'you_assets_path' + image" />
</div>
```

[image: Scroll]

For more example and documents, there a demo site: https://bfwg.github.io/ngx-drag-scroll/